# Parse cloud code with my own server returns "unauthorized"

Tags: javascript, heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

So I have my own Parse server, running heroku.

This cloud code function:

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("ReadyUp", function(request, response) {

    var fbid = request.user.get("fbid");
    var query = new Parse.Query("Spel");
    query.equalTo("lobby", fbid);
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        //_.each(results, function(spel) {
        //    spel.addUnique("ready", fbid);
        //});
        results[0].addUnique("ready", fbid);
        return Parse.Object.saveAll(results);
    }).then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

returns `{ message = unauthorized; } (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)`

Been sitting with this for a while, no luck at all. Putting `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` on top of the main.js file doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I've migrated my parse.com code to heroku and I'm also getting similar error while calling clound function.

Looks like we're missing some configuration here.

```
{
    "code": 141,
    "error": {
        "message": "unauthorized"
    }
}
```